# One line Arrow function, return multiple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am using ReactJS and I am having trouble getting an arrow function to return multiple functions.

I have a one line arrow function on an onLoad event:

```
<iframe onLoad={() => (this.handleFrame && this.setState({loadingComplete: true}))}></iframe>
```

The above code does not work. How I can return both `this.handleFrame` & `this.setState({loadingComplete: true})` on one line of code?

Comment: Do you want to return the logical-and of their results or two actual result values?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
<iframe onLoad={() => ({val1: this.handleFrame(), val2: this.setState({loadingComplete: true})})}></iframe>
```

It will return an object with two values.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call this.handleFrame:

```
<iframe onLoad={() => (this.handleFrame() && this.setState({loadingComplete: true}))}></iframe>
```

Note that this will call both functions, but it will return a boolean (true if both functions return a truthy result, otherwise not)

Also note that if your first function does not return truthy, the next function will not be called!

If you want to call all functions regardless of if they return truthy, and don't care about returning a result then do:

```
<iframe onLoad={() => { this.handleFrame(); this.setState({loadingComplete: true}) }}></iframe>
```

Comment: The question is about single line function. Single line functions shouldn't have `{}`

Comment: Thanks, a lot Dominic. Forgetting to call this.handleFrame was my main issue. However, your answer gave me a greater understanding of arrow functions, so I appreciate the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is wrong. You **cannot** `return` two items at once.

Your code is checking for `this.handleFrame`, if that is available, `this.setState({loadingComplete: true})` will be executed and the value will be returnrd. If `this.handleFrame` is not available, it will return `undefined`.

If you want to **execute** multiple functions, you can do the following.

```
<iframe onLoad={() => ((this.handleFrame() || true) && this.setState({loadingComplete: true}))}></iframe>
```

If you return `true` for `this.handleFrame()`, you don't need a `||` check.

If you want to **return** multiple functions, you can do the following.

```
<iframe onLoad={() => {handleFrame: this.handleFrame, state: this.setState({loadingComplete: true})}}></iframe>
```